# XCode 7 - TableViewController bug

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

```
class TestClass: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
code...
}
```

This is the old way to implement TableViewController in .swift now We receive an error:

1. Redunant conformance of 'TestClass' to protocol UITableViewDelegate.
2. Redunant conformance of 'TestClass' to protocol UITableViewDataSource.

And we have to remove UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource and leave only UITableViewController.

BUT now my tables are black and text inside is blue:

This happens only when you run the app on the device.
[image: TableViewController]

Tested devices: iPhone 5 (iOS 8.3), iPhone 6 (iOS 8.4)

On all simulators with iOS 9 works.

I don't want to setup iOS 9 on my devices to test it, because is full with bugs.

Tested on XCode 7 beta and XCode 7 beta 2.

Comment: Nothing in your question has anything to do with colour. What are your storyboard settings for the `UITableViewController`? Are you using the `UIAppearance` protocol anywhere? Of course, since you are using an Xcode beta this could be an Xcode beta bug. If you can generate a test case that works in the `iOS 9 simulator` but fails on `iOS 8.x devices` then you can log a bug with Apple.

Comment: Okay thankss :) I will log a bug

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewController` already conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` - that's why you see this error.

You can simply leave just `UITableViewController` and remove others

Comment: I do it and now my all TableViewControllers in my app are black and I can't fix it... Give me an answer how to fix it..